# Terminal: Add items to Accessibility Access in MacOS Mojave 10.14?

Tags: applescript, macos-mojave, osascript

Is there a way to programmatically add items (Osascript) to Accessibility Access?

I read its possible via tccutil, for example:

```
sudo tccutil.py --insert /usr/bin/osascript
```

Mojave is not letting me do this: "Error opening Database", seems like TCC is SIP protected.

Is it possible to do this with pure terminal commands?
Since i want to execute an applescript remotely via a bash script..

```
osascript /folder/myscript.scpt
```

myscript.scpt: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-25211)

Greets.

Comment: Have a look at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339509/edit-tcc-db-to-bypass-foo-app-wants-access-to-control-bar-app-on-own-machi/342699#342699